# Export Windows 8 Store data to excel file

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, export-to-excel

I've written a Windows 8 Store application using XAML/C# and a SQLite database.

From within the application I need to create an Excel file and export the data from the SQLite Database. I have no idea how to start this and even if this is supported within a Windows store application.

Can somebody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample for  export data, that is showed in ListView, to a csv file.
[This](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Export-To-CSV-Sample-b31b50cf) can help you

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I have seen that page but I really need to create an excel document as I'll be dropping data onto multiple tabs

Comment: This isn't directly supported, but you could *possibly* hack something together along the lines of the accepted answer here -> http://forums.asp.net/t/1214938.aspx